# Java Framework To create Simple Websites?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, playframework-2.0

I want to create **Website** that contains huge pages for display.I want to create them fastly.So i decided to use java framework.

I know Spring framework well and it is used to create web applications.
I think there is another Play! java Framework is present which is simple and easy to understand for begginers. So i have decided to use for for creating websites.

Please suggests me other solutions or advantages/disadvantages of play framework.
I want only **Java framework** and not other language framework. 
I want to Use only **java and HTML and JavaScript**.

Comment: Play framework is a scala framework. Sure it supports Java, but you'd better know Scala to use it.

Comment: To use play framework (especially for a site with a huge number of pages) you will definitely need a slight knowledge of Scala (even in Java version of Playframework templates use Scala)

Comment: ok! that means Scala knowlege is requisite for Play

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a couple of java web mvc framework and the most popular one is as following: 
1) Spring MVC -- the most traditional one, very powerful and cause it's spring it's quite good
2) Spring ROO -- initially a wrap around Spring MVC, provides you good Domain Driven Dev
3) Play -- most dynamic and ROR style framework, also support Scala

Below is out dated and not popular: 
1) JBoss Seam
2) Struts

If you are a java background dev, you can also look into Grails, or GoG.
Personally, I believe it's a great framework and can boost the dev time several times. However it's not as popular as RoR. There are a couple of thread comparing Grails and RoR on StackOverFlow, you can google and find it. They are all brilliant comparisons

Depends on your requirement, usually big company use Spring MVC, startup company use Play or Grails.

Thanks,
Seabook

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the **website** hosting huge pages, you don't event need a development framework like Playframework or Spring MVC, maybe CMS(content management system) like [liferay](http://www.liferay.com) is better choice.